# How to change the delay from ASA to PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I have a simple query in ASA from an IoT Hub input to send an average calculation each second to powerbi. I can see that the first data comes to PowerBi 15-20 seconds after IoT Hub receives the input. 
Is there anything I can do to decrease this delay?

Query:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(acctotal as float)) as average_shake, 
       CAST(MAX(eventTime) as datetime) as time
INTO powerbioutput
FROM iothubinput
TIMESTAMP BY eventTime
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 1)
```

Event Ordering settings are kept to default values
Late arrival Days:00, Hours:00, Minutes:00, Seconds:05
Out of order Minutes:00, Seconds:00
Action: Adjust

Comment: Increasing Streaming Units from the default 1 to maximum 6 decreased the delay to 8-10 seconds. Anything more I can do?

Comment: Can you post your query and also post your Event Ordering settings?

Comment: Adding query and settings to original question

Comment: It seems like setting all time values in Late arrival to 0 including the seconds makes it arrive much quicker. ASA is probably adding 5 seconds delay by default to guard for late arriving events.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Describe your business scenario more. What populates Event Hub? Is the eventTime column significant vs. the time the event arrived in Event Hub? If a device had a delay and the event showed up 10 seconds or 10 minutes late what would you want to do?

Comment: This is just a real time demonstration at a conference. We send measurements from sensors to IoTHub-ASA-PowerBi and show the dashboard at the screen during the presentations. That is why we need to see data as fast as we can. When I have 0 late arrival policy it adds like 3-5 seconds of delay anyway. Another thing that can affect this might be the location of our PowerBi subscription. If it is not in same data center as the Hub and ASA. Do you have any idea how to find that out? EventTime does not matter in anyways by the way.

Comment: If you go to Power BI and open the "?" menu and choose About Power BI it tells you what Azure region your Power BI is in. That might contribute. Also, I think the number and complexity of the tiles you have pinned which consume the real-time dataset may also slow down the updates. At least that's what I observed last time I tested it.

Comment: You might try removing the TIMESTAMP BY eventTime clause to see if it behaves differently. I believe it will use the IoT Hub enqueue date if you don't tell it which column to use as the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the system timestamp instead of event time, I think you will see the delay go away. Try just removing the line "TIMESTAMP BY eventTime"

Comment: By deleting just the TIMESTAMP BY, the job does not return any output at all. Is there a TIMESTAMP BY EnquedTime or similiar where I can force it to use the incoming timestamp?

Comment: By the way there is a bug in the new portal whenever I change late arrival setting seconds to 0 it is updated back to the default value of 5 seconds. Although in the old portal I can see that it updates to 0 seconds anyway

Comment: I had Drop as Late arrival policy and some inputs were dropped as they arrive a few seconds behind. I can see some minor performance difference as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can get system time - i.e. the timestamp given to the event as it flows through ASA - through:

```
SELECT System.Timestamp
```

As documented in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn834998.aspx).

Building onto Josh's response: perhaps you could try something like:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(acctotal as float)) as average_shake, 
   System.Timestamp as time
INTO powerbioutput
FROM iothubinput
TIMESTAMP BY time
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(second, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the volume of your input events and what is the number of IoTHub partitions? ASA merges data form IOTHub partitions and arranges events by time to compute aggregation defined in the query. If you have many partitions and relatively small number of events, there could be additional delays as some IoTHub partitions may not have data and ASA will be waiting for the data to appear (max delay is controlled by late arrival policy).

If this is the case, you may want to use fewer IoTHub partitions.
In general, you will see smaller latency in ASA when you process partitions in parallel (use PARTITION BY clause). The drawback is that you will end up with partial aggregate values per partition. You can probably aggregate them further in PowerBI.